# Slicer and filter on power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi, slicers

I am working a data visualization and I have removed any filter on the whole page and also turned off all the filters on the visualization as well as the page. I still see cannot see the data.

[image]

But I see the data is still getting filtered, How do I remove these?

[image]

this is how my visualization looks like.

[image]

Comment: Any slicers or timelines in the page?

Comment: @teylyn yes, This is how the power bi page looks like.  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykDUc.png

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot in your comment clearly shows two slicers that define a date range. The visual is filtered by these slicers, not by page filters or filters on the visual.  This is working as intended and is not a malfunction.

If you don't want the slicers to filter the visual, you need to configure the cross filtering for the visual. Use **Format > Edit Interactions** to control which slicers affect which visuals. Select the slicer, then click the icon on the target visual that looks like this:

[image]

In your screenshot, the visible slicers and the slicers in the pop-up of the visual have different names. That points to slicers that have been deleted from the page but are still filtering the data.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: I do not want to remove the slicer, instead want to check, why is a filter getting applied even when I have no slicer range selected over the visualization.

Comment: This is not about removing the slicer. It is about configuring which visuals the slicer will affect. Typically, a slicer affects all visuals on the page. It looks like you have had different slicers on that page before and they were set to start at July 1, but then the slicers were removed from the page. In that case, the filters are kept.